# Export data to a PDF file in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, pdf-generation

Is it possible to export data to a PDF file in SSIS?

Currently I am exporting it to a txt file using a  Flat file destination. I am using a script to rename the file, so I have tried to rename it to Filename.pdf, but when I try to open it it just says its corrupted.

I can't seem to find anything relevant in any of the searches that I have done

Comment: Changing the name of a file extention to .pdf will not format the file the way Adobe Acrobat does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply changing the extension will not help you save the file in a PDF format. You have to invoke a pdf creation program in order to save the Flat File as a PDF. You can either use the powershell, or write custom code in .net to do so.